# Support for object tags with embedded ActiveX in Mozilla/Safari

Tags: activex, cross-browser, ocx

I am using an object tag to load ActiveX extension controls like so:

```
<object name="controlcontainer" 
    width=320 
    height=240 
    codebase="./library.cab#version=1,2">
</object>
```

This works fine in IE, but we are looking into creating a port of our application for the iPad. Is there any way we can load ActiveX controls on the Mozilla/Safari platform?

Thanks,

Comment: There is no way to load ActiveX in iPad. Create webkit plugin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveX controls do not and will not ever work on Mac, the iPad, or any other non-microsoft platform. There is currently no method that I know of for creating a browser plugin of any kind on an iPad, though if there were it would be either a WebKit plugin or a NPAPI plugin.

If you want to port your application to work on firefox, chrome, etc and work on Mac, you may want to look at the [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) project, but since Apple doesn't allow such software on the iPad you'll need to approach it a different way there.